# PHP: If statement after calling a function inside a function

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
  function selectApi() {
    ...
  }

  function runApis( $a1, $a2, $a3, $formVars ) {
    global $responseUrl;
    global $responseType;

    selectApi($a1['provider'], $formVars, $a1['min_price']);
    if( $responseType !== 'valid') {
      selectApi($a2, $formVars, $a2['min_price']);
    }
    if( $responseType !== 'valid' ) {
      selectApi($a3, $formVars, $a3['min_price']);
    }
  }

  runApis( $api1, $api2, $api3, $formVars );
```

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is to call the runApis() function, which will then run the selectApi() function for the first api. At the end of the selectApi() function, the $responseType variable will be set. I then want to run it again for the second api if the $responseType is not valid.

But currently it just runs the selectApi() function then continues on with the code outside of the enclosing runApis() function.

The global variables set here are used later on in the code outside the function.

Comment: You're approaching this wrong, as it isn't valid PHP syntax. "selectApi" needs to be it's own function, outside of "runApis".

Comment: It is it's own function outside of runApis, I just didn't include it in the snippet

Comment: That part would have been helpful as it's related code.

Comment: How is `$responseType` set?  Just a guess but try `$GLOBALS['responseType']` or have `runApis()` return it.

Comment: Okay I'll include the other code, bare with

Comment: Apologies, the issue was actually not the one at hand, it was caused by me referencing $a2 instead of $a2['provider'] below. What should I do in this instance on stack overflow, answer my own question or close it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't asking about this...  But I would simplify this code to:

```
function runApis( array $apis, array $formVars ) {
    global $responseUrl;
    global $responseType;

    foreach($apis as $api){
        selectApi($api, $formVars, $api['min_price']);
        if($responseType === 'valid'){
            break;
        }
    }
}

runApis( [$api1, $api2, $api3], $formVars );
```

This makes it so that you are following the DRY principle (which is one of the most important coding principles I am aware of, and the ignoring of which is the cause of many many bugs).

Also, I know you aren't asking, but generally globals are bad.  You could pass $responseType by reference using the & symbol, or just return it from the runApis function (pass by reference is a code smell in most languages, so returning it is a better choice).

And...  Are you using an IDE you can debug code in?  I find it amazingly simpler to debug php using phpstorm.  Using a real-time debugger makes your life so so much simpler.  And, syntax highlighting will frequently show you bugs in advance.

Anyways, I know you didn't ask for help coding, but I thought you might benefit from this (teach a man to fish vs giving him a fish).

Good Luck!